# What is happening in Map[Function[x, x^2], a + b + c] from the Pure Function tutorial

Tags: functions, pure-function, example

The [Pure Function tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) gives an example: `Map[Function[x, x^2], a + b + c]`.

I would expect the output to be `(a + b + c)^2`, but instead it returns `a^2 + b^2 + c^2`.  `Map[Function[x,x^2],a+b+c]//FullForm` even gives `Plus[Power[a,2],Power[b,2],Power[c,2]]` which provides no clarity.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not the pure function you trip over, it's the property of `Map` : it not only maps into elements of a list, but just as well into `Plus` or `Times` or into the function with head `travis` (pardon my pun).
`Map[z, travis[a, b, c]]`  gives `(* travis[z[a],z[b],z[c]] *)`

Comment: Whoa, trippy! `Map[#+1&,f[A[x]+B[x]]+g[A[x]+B[x]],2]` $\to$ `2+f[1+A[x]+B[x]]+g[1+A[x]+B[x]]`.  Why didn't I end up with `2+A[x]+B[x]` inside `f` and `g`?  It mapped into the `Plus[f,g]` twice (once for `f` and once for `g`), but it only mapped into the `Plus[A,B]` at level two once?  For which one, `A` or `B`?

Comment: You can use `FullForm[exp]` to see what the heads are at every level of an expression. If you want map to work *only* at the specified level, `lev` you need to use curly brackets: `Map[f,expr,{lev}]`. If you omit them, `Map` will map at *every* level up to `lev`.

Comment: Weird, `Map[...,...,3]` gives `3+A[x]+B[x]`.  I guess I know what help page I'm reading next.

Comment: @gpap I understood (yeah right) that `Map` would map into every level up to `lev`, but if I'm following the levels right, in my comment above, it didn't map into the second level the same way it mapped into the first level.  Mapping into `Plus[f,g]` gave `2+f+g`.  Mapping into `Plus[A,B]` ... nevermind, `f[]` and `g[]` would be the second (and third?) level(s) wouldn't they?

Comment: @TravisBemrose because the heads at the second level are `f` and `g` so map does `f[whatever]`$\rightarrow$`f[1+whatever]`. At the third level the head is `Plus`. You can replace `TreeForm` for my `FullForm` to see the level hierarchy more clearly